# Get Pdf form data filled on browser and get field values as post data similar to html form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have opened editable pdf on browser and I am able to add entries on pdf. Following is the html sample code which I have written to display editable pdf on browser:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="test3.php" method="POST">
        <iframe src="AbcPdfForm.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px;"></iframe>
        <input type="submit" id="submitpdf" name="submitpdf" value="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Submit button is outside the pdf document. On click of submit button, I am unable to get field values of pdf form.
I have tried pdftk library also "https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk". From this library, I have tried feature "**Get PDF data**" through php code. I am unable to get field values from this library too. I have received only field names of pdf file.
I have tried to receive field values using following procedure:

I have entered information in pdf opened through browser. Then I saved that pdf with name 'data.pdf' and write following code from pdktk.

```
use mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf;
$pdf = new Pdf('data.pdf');
$data = $pdf->getData(); 
print_r($data);                           // Get metadata info about pdf file

$data1 = $pdf->getDataFields();
print_r($data);                           // Get field names, field type info of fields.
```

I am unable to get field values through this pdftk library. There are lot of libraries available for .net, java and python for converting pdf form to html form and then get post information. But didn't find anything for PHP. I tried to handle this situation in indirect way also like first fill data in pdf through browser and then save that pdf through browser and then get fields of newly saved pdf through pdftk library, but pdftk only fetching field names, not able to get field values.
There is another feature of pdftk "**Fill Form**". In this fetaure, pdf is filled with hard-coded values through php.
But I want to fill pdf on browser and get those filled values in php file.

I will be very thankful to anyone if anyone suggests me how to fulfill my requirements. Any of the following direct/indirect approaches will work for me:

```
 * Either by converting pdf form to html form. User will fill html form and we can directly get submitted values.

 * Get Pdf values through javascript on browser which user has filled on pdf opened on browser.

 * Get values through library for php or javascript.
```

Comment: The user would need to download the PDF, alter it, save it, and then upload it again by selecting it from a file input in a HTML form. What you're doing now is just embedding a temporary copy of the PDF in the  user's browser. It does not get submitted anywhere when you submit your form. I think you've misunderstood how the web works.

Comment: IMHO you'd be better off just creating a HTML form, and let the user enter the values that way. If you need to generate a PDF later, then you can use the submitted data together with a PDF template, and create a PDF containing the filled data, just as if the user had entered it directly. That'll be more user friendly than getting them to download, edit and re-upload a PDF file.

Comment: @ADyson - I also want to know how to create HTML form from Pdf form. My requirement is: I have pdf form. I want to render same form in HTML form so that I can get information posted by user. My actual requirement is to get information filled by user either from pdf through library or convert pdf to HTML so that I can have information posted by user. I don't have filling form directly in HTML form. I just have pdf form. My requirement is just to fetch information filled by user.

Comment: "I also want to know how to create HTML form from Pdf form"...type it out by hand. There's no shortcut. The way you implement a HTML form is totally different. You must implement it yourself. But once it's done, of course it can be used forever.

Comment: @ADyson - There are lot of libraries available for other platforms like java, .net or python for converting pdf form to html form, but didn't find anything for PHP. I can't type pdf form directly because form may vary everytime. I need dynamic solution, either in the form of library like this 'https://pdfix.net/'. This library provides pdf form to html form conversion for .net, java and python.

Comment: Yes. There's nothing like that for PHP directly which I'm aware of, hence my comment. That particular one you've linked to has a command-line utility though, so you could potentially invoke it from PHP.

Comment: P.S. why will the form be different every time? What is the scenario here? Are your users designing custom forms or something?

Comment: @Adyson - There are multiple forms actually. So, we can't build HTML form by seeing pdf form. In future, new pdf forms may be added.

Comment: Is this going to be a very frequent thing, to add new forms? Or just occasionally? And again, who is adding them? Users, whenever they wish? Or certain people, through a controlled process? it's still unclear (I did ask!). If it's the latter, you could perfectly well just re-develop the forms as HTML forms yourself. If the former, then yes you need a tool (which hopefully produces satisfactory results in all cases).

Comment: hey, did you figure it out yet? on the same boat here, please respond soon.